# I Need Opinions Regarding Building a Virtual Classroom

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I want to build a website that represents a simple virtual class in which the teacher uses a webcam to record his lesson and the students can watch the lesson live (while its being recorded), the whole idea is easy because I don't need any other features (the students just sign in and watch) and the teacher (just signs in as Tutor and records).

Now what I have to say is that I have a good programming experience using C#.net and some WPF but I want to know how to do it the best way that would make it as fast as possible so that the image doens't flicker, should I use WCF ? should I use ASP.Net ? what should I use ? and can you give me a very very very brief description of the steps I have to do while developing this project.

Thanks verymuch for everyone . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look at Silverlight WebCam (because you can write it in C#): [Link1](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prvn_131971/937/), [Link2](http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2010/06/push-and-pull-silverlight-webcam.html) and
[Sample app for two way video chat](http://www.silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-samples/video-chat-35809/)

You can also use Flash: [Link1](http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/326194)

You can also use ActiveX, but that is such a bad suggestion that I won't even bother Googling an example for you. ;)

For the webpage itself I think most programmers will agree that MVC is the way to go.

Comment: For a alternative aproach have a look at http://archvirtual.com/?p=2167 and http://www.opensimulator.org/. You can stream video directly into OpenSimulator. There are web based viewers for OpenSimulator.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to use ASP MVC this will let you to develop an environment quickly, so you could focus in the main problem (the transmision of video streams and the performance). If you have experience in C#... then you're able to learn the basics of MVC only in a few hours. (try doing the tutorials in http://www.asp.net/mvc)